# What word do we use to talk about doing a project?

Tags: single-word-requests

in the following sentence what word should I use?

```
Many of the projects are .... well but not maintained very well after being submitted to the clinets.
```

conducted / carried out / done / Operated or what?

Thanks

Comment: The context is not very clear, but considering that the subsequent stage seems to be maintenance, I would use the word **developed**.

Comment: They seem to be 'presented' well but, after submission, are not properly maintained.

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- implemented, managed, performed, completed

But I prefer *conducted*, from your list over my options.